# Error with .\SampleApp\node_modules\ionic-angular\package.json file

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

hi friends i am facing this error (check red color error)every time i creating ionic project.
i dont know why its coming.
please help me to solve

[image: Terminal screen shot] Please solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the same command with --verbose at the end.

> ionic start myIonicApp tabs --verbose

Also install cordova:

> npm install -g cordova

to see if this fixes the problem.